# Install Xcache for dedicated

Tags: apache-2.2, php, cache

Hell I had try install xcache

> ```
> http://xcache.lighttpd.net/wiki/InstallFromSource
> ```

But in step

```
~/src/xcache $ make
~/src/xcache $ su
~/src/xcache # make install
```

My dedicated showed an error

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Which exact line through the error?

Chances are, `./configure` threw an error (and hence didn't generate the make file).  Check the output for that command and see if it's saying something's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This usually works best (from the shell, inside the base of the source code directory):

```
./configure && make && make install
```

The `&&` will only execute the next command if the last one was successful.  If there was an error in the `./configure` command you should see it right after it stops running.